# Django sort on paginated results

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am creating a list view in Django 2 using CBV. The pagination is working however I am now trying to add sorting to my pagination. This sorting will work whereby when the user selects a column, it will append a GET query string and then when I render my view, I will order_by the QueryResult.

This is working however I am now only fetching 4 entries (my current page) as opposed to the entire set. My problem is that I need it to filter only on the current page results but then return the current page and the rest of the results.

This is my current solution:

```
class AccountList(ListView):
    ordering_dict = {
        'pk':'asc', 'is_active':'asc','created':'asc'
        }
    template_name = "marketing/comm_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'comms'
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_queryset(self):
        type_filter = self.request.GET.get('type', 'all')

        queryset = Comm.objects.values('pk', 'name', 'is_active', 'created')

        page_field = self.request.GET.get('page')
        paginator = Paginator(queryset, 4)

        try:
            pages = paginator.page(page_field)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            pages = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            pages = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        start_index = pages.start_index()
        end_index = pages.end_index()

        queryset = Comm.objects.values('pk', 'name', 'is_active', 'created').filter(pk__gte=start_index, pk__lte=end_index)

        order_by_field = self.request.GET.get('order_by')
        if order_by_field:
            if self.ordering_dict[order_by_field] == 'asc':
                self.ordering_dict[order_by_field] = 'desc'
            else:
                self.ordering_dict[order_by_field] = 'asc'
                order_by_field = '-'+order_by_field    
            queryset = queryset.order_by(order_by_field)
        else:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('-created') 
        return queryset
```

Any help is appreciated, I am using Django 2 and Python 3.6. Thanks!

The general issue is that I want to be able to sort by column only on the current page of my paginated results

Comment: You need to solve this problem on the client side and not on the server side. Use a datatable widget that does client side sorting on the columns; it will sort only what is shown on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for sorting:

```
return sorted(queryset, key=lambda k: k.column_name])
```

this will iterate on `queryset` and sort them by `column_name`.

you can check `k['column_name']` instead of `k.column_name` too and see which one is gonna be works for you.

more info about `sorted` function in python [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted).

Comment: That sounds like it would work however I only want to sort on the current page, if I don't split out the page results. It sorts the entire database and I only want to have sorting for the current page (not every entry). Is that possible?

Comment: Also attempting: 
   

     order_by_field = self.request.GET.get('order_by')
     return sorted(queryset, key=lambda k: k[order_by_field])
 
I am getting a key_error however I have my order_by querystring set to ?order_by= is_active

Answer (score 0):

You can add blow class to your model to return query result by the order you giving to

```
Class Meta:
    ordeing = ('col_name') # in order
    ordeing = ('-col_name') # in reverse
```

another way is to create a manager class for your model. create a function to return whatever you need and just call it where ever you need.

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_my_query(self, order):
         #Write your query
```