# Use order by in pagination result Django

Tags: django, pagination

I want to order by only pagination result, for example in the first page I get two products *(the meaning of this mehsul is a product)* and when I get ordering I want to order these two products.

```py
    def animal(request,slug):
        mehsul=Product.objects.filter(animal_type=slug)
        animal_count=2
        paginator=Paginator(mehsul,animal_count)
        page_number=request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        ordering = request.GET.get('ordering')

    if ordering:
        mehsul = Product.objects.filter(animal_type=slug)
        paginator=Paginator(mehsul,animal_count)
        page_number=request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj=paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request,'animal.html',context={'mehsullar':page_obj})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to order the queryset you've created? If so, you can use the Django ORM `order_by()` function - see the Django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Your code that follows `if ordering:` is a duplicate of the code that precedes it, I would suggest checking the ordering at the start of your view and then putting it into the `order_by()` function if it exists

Comment: All the products you mentioned are order by-ed. I did not want order by all filtering product i want only order by page_obj

Comment: What do you mean order by page_obj? The page_obj is the pagination result that contains two of your items that use in your template - if you want to order the results of the paginator then you would order the model object first

Comment: I now I want order by pagination result when i paginate i get 2 product i whant order this product

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340223/django-sort-on-paginated-results

Comment: 0sVoid yes like this

Comment: But they did not answer correctly